# GCD of a non linear list Lisp

Tags: list, common-lisp, greatest-common-divisor

How can I get the GCD of a non-linear list using Map functions in Common Lisp?

```
defun gcd (a b)
    (cond
      ((eq b 0) a)
      (t (gcd b (mod a b)))))

(defun gcdall (l)
    (cond
        ((null l) nil)
        (t (...))
)
)
```

I don't quite understand how to use map-functions, so any help/hints would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to use map? If not you could just find the gcd of the car, the gcd of the cdr, and take the gcd of both of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want correctly, that's easy enough:

```
(defun nested-gcd (list)
  (reduce #'gcd list :key (lambda (elt)
                            (if (consp elt)
                                (nested-gcd elt)
                              elt))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what a non-linear list is, but you can get the greatest common divisor by using `gcd`, which is part of the standard.  If you mean some kind of tree, you might have to flatten it first.

Comment: By non-linear list I mean a list of form (2 (12 10) 18 (3)). I thought there must be a direct method without flattening it.

Comment: Gcd is associative, so you can do it step by step inline with a tree traversal (which is what gsg showed).